# Get Flash player install warning even though latest flash player is installed

Tags: flash

We have a site that delivers training material. This training material uses Flash to make it more dynamic. The problem we are seeing is that we get a message from the webpage stating:

> The simulation requires Flash Player 7.0 or higher to play. Do you
>   want to download it from http://www.macromedia.com/go/getFlashPlayer?

What we are trying to establish is is this error message content specific or is it a User PC issue.

Looking at the download location url it states Macromedia as the source so its reference to Macromedia is very old.
By content specific I am thinking that in the source code its referring to the version 7.0 and Macromedia site.

Apparently the strange thing is the user reported this to be working around 6 weeks ago.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks
JC

Comment: Can you provide a link to this website?

Comment: and is this happening only in one PC? If yes, it could be an adware/malware.

Comment: Which browser(s) gives this issue? Are you using the`embed` tag to display your SWF file (Flash app)? Would be easier if you made a basic example  page that shows your issue in action for assessment...